# I need find excell sheet 1 value and print to data new sheet only what i need from sheet1 using java

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have 2 excel sheets:

- Sheet 1 has lot of id and specific data for that ids
- Sheet 2 only has some of the ids

I need to get relevant data from sheet 1 to sheet 2.

Sheet 2:
[image]

```
String input2 = "C:/Users/CHATHURANGA/Desktop/fiverr/New folder/Sheet2.xlsx";

FileInputStream excelFile2 = new FileInputStream(new File(input2));
Workbook workbook3 = new XSSFWorkbook(excelFile2);
Sheet datatypeSheet2 = workbook3.getSheetAt(0);
Iterator<Row> iterator2 = datatypeSheet2.iterator();

while (iterator2.hasNext()) {

    Row currentRow = iterator2.next();
    Iterator<Cell> cellIterator2 = currentRow.iterator();

    while (cellIterator2.hasNext()) {

        Cell currentCell = cellIterator2.next();
        //getCellTypeEnum shown as deprecated for version 3.15
        //getCellTypeEnum ill be renamed to getCellType starting from version 4.0
        if (currentCell.getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.STRING) {
            System.out.print(currentCell.getStringCellValue() + "--");
        } else if (currentCell.getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.NUMERIC) {
            System.out.print(currentCell.getNumericCellValue() + "--");
        }

    }
    System.out.println();

}
```

I will read sheet 1 in the same way as shown above.

How do I match the ids from sheet 2 with the relevant data from sheet 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A prototype for you:

Create function read data from sheet1:

```
public HashMap<String, String> getSheet1Data (Sheet sheet1){
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    for (Row row : sheet1){
        map.put (row.getCell(1).getValueAsString(), row.getCell(2).getValueAsString());
     }
     return map;
}
```

In main class create a function to populate data to sheet2

```
public void populateSheet2 (HashMap<String, String> map, Sheet sheet2){
    for (Row row : sheet2){
        String id = row.getCell(1).getValueAsString();
        String data = map.get(id);
        row.createCell(2).setValue(data);
    }
}
```